# Multiple OpenTK Controls: Why does only one initially render?

Tags: vb.net, opengl, opentk

I'm trying to implement 2+ stand-alone OpenTK GLControls. On the form load, I want them both to be rendered and displayed right when they load. In the picture below, you'll see my issue. One is rendered correctly, but the other is left unrendered.

GL Screenshot before mouse_drag

[image: GL Screenshot before mouse_drag]

Doing a mouse_drag action on the erring control will cause it to render correctly.

GL Screenshot after mouse_drag

[image: GL Screenshot after mouse_drag]

**Here is the code for my main form. It creates and adds the GLControl objects:**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports OpenTK
Imports OpenTK.Graphics
Imports OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL

Public Class MultipleDisplay

    Private Sub MultipleDisplay_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'Creating and adding the controls.
        'The load event prompts the user to choose a file to build the objects.
        Dim task2 As GLControlTask = New GLControlTask()
        task2.MakeCurrent()
        task2.Width = 400
        task2.Height = 400
        task2.Top = 0
        task2.Left = 450
        Me.Controls.Add(task2)

        'The load event prompts the user to choose a file to build the objects.
        Dim task1 As GLControlTask = New GLControlTask()
        task1.MakeCurrent()
        task1.Width = 400
        task1.Height = 400
        task1.Top = 0
        task1.Left = 0
        Me.Controls.Add(task1)

        'INITIAL PAINT
        task2.MakeCurrent()
        task2.Invalidate()

        task1.MakeCurrent()
        task1.Invalidate()

    End Sub
End Class
```

**Here is the code for my GLControlTask class that extends the GLControl Class:**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports OpenTK
Imports OpenTK.Graphics
Imports OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL

Public Class GLControlTask
    Inherits GLControl

    Private arm As Arm

    Private rotator As ArcBall

    Private glLoaded As Boolean = False
    Private cameraAngleX As Single
    Private cameraAngleY As Single
    Private cameraAngleZ As Single
    Private prevMouseX As Integer
    Private prevMouseY As Integer
    Private glMouseDown As Boolean

    Private lightAngleX As Single
    Private lightAngleY As Single
    Private lightDistance As Single

    'Perspective Attributes
    Private eyeOffset As Vector3
    Private boxRadius As Single
    Private boxOffset As Vector3

    Private isPerspective As Boolean
    Private hasLighting As Boolean
    Private hasFog As Boolean


    Public Sub New()
        arm = New Arm()
        arm.loadFromXML()
        'MsgBox(arm.ToString())

        isPerspective = False
        hasLighting = True
        hasFog = False

        eyeOffset.X = 0
        eyeOffset.Y = 0
        eyeOffset.Z = 1000.0F

        lightDistance = 10000.0F
        lightAngleX = 0.0F
        lightAngleY = 0.0F

        boxRadius = 2.5F
    End Sub

    Private Sub Me_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        glLoaded = True

        GL.ClearColor(Color.Black)
        rotator = New ArcBall(Me)
        Me_Resize(Nothing, New EventArgs())
    End Sub

    Private Sub Me_Resize(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
        If glLoaded = False Then
            Return
        End If

        GL.Viewport(0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height)
        rotator.windowResized()
        Me.Invalidate()
    End Sub

    'PAINT CODE REMOVED

    Private Sub On_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseDown
        glMouseDown = True
        Me.MakeCurrent()
        prevMouseX = e.X
        prevMouseY = e.Y

        rotator.mousePressed(e.X, e.Y)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Me_MouseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseUp
        glMouseDown = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Me_MouseMove(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
        If glMouseDown = False Then
            Return
        End If

        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            rotator.mouseDragged(e.X, e.Y)
            Me.Invalidate()
        End If

        prevMouseX = e.X
        prevMouseY = e.Y
    End Sub

    Private Function deg2Rad(ByVal degrees As Double) As Double
        Return degrees * Math.PI / 180
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Anyone? I know I'm a new player, but you will be doing NASA a great service!

Answer (score 0):

I had a simillar error in a project i am making, and the problem was with windows7-openTK compatibility. 
First it seems that you should never use Windows7 aero theme while using openTK. 
In my case that was not the only solution. You must try also updating the latest drivers of your GPU (i've seen some posts in OpenTK forums where people fix wrong drawing issues like that) but still in my case did't work. As I had a really old GPU I needed to buy a new one and like that I solved all my problems with the graphics.

It may not be that but I can't find any error in your code. If you can test your proyect in a XP machine and if it is properly working there try uppdating your graphic drivers.

Also I have seen people fixing this problem using glColor4 function instead of Glcolor3.

I hope it helps.